# How can I export table data from SQL Server Object Explorer and Insert into PostgreSQL Database tables

Tags: sql-server, postgresql

In DB migration process from SQL Server to PostgreSQL 9.6 . I have managed to create tables with same name in PostgreSQL. but in order to copy all tables data from SQL to PGSQL I am facing difficulties as "SQL Server Object Explorer" does not have "export data into csv" facility and even if it does it is very time consuming too do it for each table .
Is there a way to perform this action? Any kind of lead would be

Comment: There's no "magic" script out data button no. You're best of creating an ETL process to migrate the data from one service to the other. That might be by exporting all the data from SQL Server to separate CSV files (one for each table) and then importing it into PostgreSQL, it might be using an actual ETL tool like SSIS to move it from one data engine to the other. If you take the time to [search](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=Export+data+from+SQL+Server+to+PostgreSQL) you'll get a wealth of tips, suggestions, and solutions.

Comment: Might also want to take a look at MSSQL Foreign Data Wrapper[FDW](https://github.com/tds-fdw/tds_fdw.  FYI, Postgres 9.6 goes EOL November 2021. If possible you might want to migrate to a newer version.